# Relocating to another Schengen country with Portugal D7 Visa

Tags: resident-permit, schengen, relocation, portugal

Suppose I apply for this Portugal D7 Visa, which I hear is a residence permit.
Can I use it to relocate to another country like the Netherlands or Spain upon collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, long term visa are only for the country you apply for.
And even short term visa are mostly just for the plans you present when you apply.